# Kivy window dont't show up - AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'namedtuple'

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Why I'm getting this error --> `AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'namedtuple'`. Whats wrong with my code..

I'm using python 3.5.2 on windows. When I execute my code on IDLE it can run - show up the kivy window, but when I execute `C:\POS\operator\python operator.py` it failed.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class OperatorWindow(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class OperatorApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return OperatorWindow()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    OperatorApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your file name is at fault here since there's also a standard library module called [operator](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/operator.html). I've got the same error but when I renamed your sample code from `operator.py` to `test.py`, it worked normally.

Comment: Oo..it is just a file name?? Ok I got it. Thanks a lot, bro. Newbies here.